# get someone to do something

Tags: causatives

I convinced him that it was a good book so he would buy it. When he did, I borrowed it from him and read it.

> a. So you made him buy the book so you could read it?
>
> b. So you had him buy the book so you could read it?
>
> c. So you got him to buy the book so you could read it?

Which of the sentences (a), (b) and (c) could be used in this context?

I am simply convincing someone to buy a book, which he might or might not need.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Option C - you "got him" to buy the book - is the one that best implies that you *coaxed* or *influenced* him to do it, perhaps *manipulated* him into believing that he wanted it so that he ultimately felt like he made the decision himself. This is because "got" refers to the *end goal*, not *how* you got there.

"Made him buy the book" suggests a degree of *force* was used - that you perhaps gave him no choice.

"Had him buy the book" also suggests that you were direct in the way you got your result, perhaps asking him outright to buy it.